# Defining global method for all classes

Tags: javascript, class, methods, global

Is there any way to define global methods for all classes?

Is easier to describe it with code...

```
Class.myMethod(){}

var Foo = function(){}
var Bar = function(){}

Foo.myMethod();
Bar.myMethod();
```

I know, its to strange, but i need it.

If it´s possible, how can i get the class variable in the method code:

```
Class.myMethod(){
    var anything; //anything should contains current class.
}

var Foo = function(){}
var Bar = function(){}

Foo.myMethod(); // anything should be Foo
Bar.myMethod(); // anything should be Bar
```

Comment: Function.prototype.methodName = function(){ //your function }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "classes" in Javascript. However, `Foo` and `Bar` are constructors, i.e. they are functions, and inherit from the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) <s>class</s> 's [`.prototype` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype). So you can do

```
Function.prototype.myMethod = function(){
    var anything = this; // refers to the current constructor function
    console.log(anything.name); // for example
}
```

```
function Foo(){}
function Bar(){}

Foo.myMethod(); // "Foo"
Bar.myMethod(); // "Bar"
```

Comment: Perfect. I tried with Function.method, now works with your answer. Thanks.